# How to reverse this projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, projection

I have a simple pinhole-style perspective projection:

$v = \begin{bmatrix}  w_x - W(u_x / 2) \\
                      w_y - W(u_y / 2) \\
                      W(u_y / tan(\theta / 2)) \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

$output \ ray  = \hat{v}$

where $u$ is a two-dimensional vector of screen sizes, $\theta$ is the vertical field-of-view, $w$ is an input pixel coordinate, and $W$ represents pixel width (needed for anti-aliasing).

I'm interested in reversing this projection, so finding $w$ given an output ray. At the moment I use this method:

$w = (\hat{v} \ / \ (\hat{v}_z \ / \ (u_y \ / \ tan(\theta \ / \ 2))))_{xy} + u \ / \ 2$

But (as far as I can see) it only maps to points outside the range described by $u$ (so ((0, screen-width), (0, screen-height))). What am I missing?

Comment: It could be that I don't have the requisite knowledge for this problem, but I don't understand this question. What is $`v$ and $\hat{v}$, and how do they relate to $v$ or the equation above? What about $W$? By saying $u = uW$, are you implying that $W$ is the scalar $1$?

Comment: I'm transcribing from imperative code (instructions), so some of the logic is a bit messy. I mean to say that screen sizes scale to match effective pixel width (=> the domain scales to match the number of discrete areas through which directions can be projected). I changed my typography around to reflect your other question :)